# Media Manager similar to iTunes for Android

Tags: windows, android, media-manager

I recently bought an Android device after several years as an iOS user. One of the things I liked about iOS was iTunes. It organizes my media files nicely and makes it easy to sync with my device. Is there anything similar that will work with my Android? The Play Store's music manager doesn't work for me because it only supports audio files. I'm also not interested in uploading my files to the internet, just syncing what I want locally.

A solution must include:

- support for video & audio
- folder management
- metadata management
- device sync
- Windows 7 support

Some other features I would like but aren't necessary:

- dynamic playlists
- play counts

Comment: As it stands I think this question is just going to turn into a popularity contest as there are a LOT of players in this field and you have not added anything that makes your needs specific enough to make a recommendation of one over another other that user preference/popularity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [Banshee](http://banshee.fm/). Banshee is cross-platform (and open source) and is quite similar to the iTunes interface.

Some features:

- Support for audio and video
- Folder and meta data management
- Sync with an Android device or any iOS device
- Ability to buy music from the Amazon store, right from Banshee
- "Queue tracks" allows you to queue up a track or let Auto DJ take over
- Shuffle
- Cover art
- Search
- Smart playlists (similar to iTunes)

Screenshots

[image: Banshee screenshot 1]

[image: Banshee screenshot 2]